# How to highlight a border of an Image View when I clicked imageview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-imageview

I have the list of images in horizontal view in android. If I click particular Image of an Image view have to highlight on border color programmtically.
How can I do that for highlighted border of an Image View.
Thanks in Advance.

[image: Want to display border like as mentioned below]

I want to display like this border of an ImageView when user clicked a single image of an ImageView.

CODE

```
horizontalimage=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearimage);
                                               // final RelativeLayout r1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_border);
                                             //   frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout
  if(multipleimage.length()>0) {
  for (int j = 0;j<multipleimage.length();j++)
    {
    pimages=multipleimage.getJSONObject(j);
    JSONObject oneimage=multipleimage.getJSONObject(0);
    ii= new ImageView(singleshooppingcart.this);
    multipleimages=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.singleimage);

   ii.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams image = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   image.width=100;
   image.height=1
   image.setMargins(5,0,0,0);


   final String multimgs=pimages.getString("original_res");
   String oneimg=oneimage.getString("original_res");


   String[] img2 = multimgs.split("\\.");
   String imagone=productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id")+  '/' + img2[0] + '(' + '1' + '0' + '0' + ')' + '.' + img2[1];
   String singleiamges=productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id")+  '/' + oneimg;
// displayimages=productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id")+  '/' + multimgs[];
   YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(imagone, ii, options);
   YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(singleiamges, multipleimages, options);

   ii.setLayoutParams(image);
 // ii.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgviewpress);
 //  ii.setBackground(R.drawable.imgviewpress);
                                                       /* GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
     gd.setColor(R.drawable.imageviewhighlight); // Changes this drawbale to use a single color instead of a gradient
     gd.setCornerRadius(5);
                  // gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);
     ii.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);*/

     horizontalimage.addView(ii);
     ii.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

   Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.imgviewpress);
   ii.setBackground(highlight);
   int indexOfImage = horizontalimage.indexOfChild(view);
   String img1=String.valueOf(indexOfImage);



// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),img1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
         images = multipleimage.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(img1)).getString(String.valueOf("original_res"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),images,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      // multipleimages.setImageResource(indexOfImage);
         try 
         YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id")+"/"+images, multipleimages, options);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }

        // String img1=String.valueOf(indexOfImage);
     // YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(displayimages[indexOfImage], multipleimages, options);
 }
             });
```

Comment: you can do a quick work around like this. This may not be the original answer however it may works.. You put a View under, ImageView and put a gap between View and ImageView of 2 dip. Then when you touch the ImageView, just change the color of View for few sec in animation or something and then get back to its original state.

Comment: Give it a StateList background (just xml, no Java required). EASY.

Comment: did you try with selector?

Comment: I am wrote everything for programmatically

Comment: post some code here what you tried so far

Comment: Did you tried ImageButton Instread of ImageView

Comment: No, I didn't use ImageButton

Comment: why dont you use selector?

Comment: You can do it simply by changing image on click to other image with yellow border...

Comment: how to do that i get images from json url

Comment: You can add a click or touch listner on that image and make a borded. check my answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Create a drawable file, in the drawable folder.

highlight.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:color="#FFC830"
        android:width="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

2. ImageView in your activity

   ```
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/iv_test"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:padding="3dp"
   android:src="@drawable/yourImageName"
   android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>
   ```

Here padding is important.

3. Inside activity code

   ```
   imv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.highlight);
           imv.setBackground(highlight);
           //
           //Do your other stuff here.
           //
       }
   });
   ```

If you want to remove the background, use this code :

```
imv.setBackground(null);
```

In the activity xml, the padding attribute is important because the highlight background will take the same size of the imageview. So if there is any image in the imageview we will not be able to see the background/highlight. So the padding attribute pushes the image a bit inwards, letting the highlight to be seen.

**Output**

[image: First]
[image: When Clicked]

**UPDATE**

Inside you code implement View.OnClickListener.

And change your onClick() method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.highlight );
    for (int j=0;j<ii.length;j++)
    {
        if (ii[j].getBackground()!=null) {
            ii[j].setBackground(null);
        }
    }
    v.setBackground(highlight);

    //
    //Do what you want to do when clicking on the imageview
    //
}
```

And right now you are using

```
ii=new ImageView(singleshooppingcart.this);
```

make it an array and use it like this

```
ii[i]=new ImageView(singleshooppingcart.this);
```

Change this

```
ii.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {

 Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imgviewpress);
ii.setBackground(highlight);
```

to

```
    ii[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```

Here i is the looping variable.

This way you will have objects for all your imageViews. and all these imageviews will have a ClickEvent which we have set.

Comment: I have list of images in horizontal view,but it showed for last image only not of other images.

Comment: this border will be set to the imageview with which you called the setBackground() function. Please check if you have used the same imageview object.
Then Again, are the images inside a horizontal scrollview or just a horizontal linearlayout...?

Comment: Only for imageview have to set this border not for linear layout

Comment: could you show the code you used to set the highlight, please. If see the code, i may be able to help out more.

Comment: i used view to got the index , view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgviewpress);                                          now it's displaying for all the image but if i click one image view show that border,then again if i next imageview make invisble border to first image view like that want to display

Comment: I have updated my onClick(View v) method. Please check.This way border of all imageview will be set to null. and then the clicked imageview will have a border.

Comment: i used array of  Image View and setOnClickListener(this) but it's doesn't workout.any other solution

Answer (score 1):

put image in a `RelativeLayout` and add a margin of 1dp and make invisible on start.
Then

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        relativeLayout.SetVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess using View.OnTouchListener is more appropriate.

Comment: View.OnTouchListener is better, You are right VoidExplorer

Comment: But I need setOnClickListener for highlighted an imageview

Comment: It depends on the highlight purpose. If you want to show what the user is SELECTING, it is better to use OnTouchListener because the highlight effect is activated once the user press on the image. If you want to show what the user is SELECTED, then setOnClickListener is also appropriate because the highlight effect is activated when the user left the finger on the image.

Comment: i need when user is SELECTED highlight effect can be activate

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your imageView keep into relative layout. e.g.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_border"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then add the following java code. Something like this

```
final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_border);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    imageView.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            layout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
        }
    });
```

Comment: whats the problem are you facing?

Comment: If i am using Relative Layout for an Image View got error

Comment: What's the error message you got. Can you write here?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Image view with linear layout and image with some padding 
basically change the color of the layout this will provide border for image view

On click use this,

```
customImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     //use either v.getchild(position) or v.findViewById(R.id.borderlayout)
        LinearLayout borderlayout = v.getChild(0);
     // change the border color or visibility you like to do
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GradientDrawable

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(0xFF00FF00); // Changes this drawbale to use a single color instead of a gradient
        gd.setCornerRadius(5);
        gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);
        Imageview imgs= (Imageview )findViewById(R.id.imgviw);
        imgs.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

Comment: No,I don't want to display like this i just want to display when user click an imageview border color only activated

Comment: see above i uploaded one image like this i want to display

Comment: It is displaying whole background how can i display only border color

Comment: how you getting image ??

Comment: I used selector   ii.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageviewhighlight); IT's working but if i press imageview only highlighted  imageview

Comment: after clicked an imageview color must be highlighted

Comment: <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E6E4E0"/>
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#F9C11E"/>
            <padding android:left="3dp"
                android:top="3dp"
                android:right="3dp"
                android:bottom="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item> Like this i used