# Checkable Imageview kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a few imageviews and want to add border if one of them is clicked. How can I do this using Kotlin? I checked  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430322/checkable-imageview) question but could not find a way to do it.

Comment: you can check the accepted answer in your given link. that solution is best

Comment: Please check below link := https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000700/how-to-highlight-a-border-of-an-image-view-when-i-clicked-imageview-in-android

Comment: @gulabpatel, I use fragments and write in Kotlin. Unfortunately, could not convert the java code...

Comment: there is no code. only create selector and set them as background of your checkbox